# NodeJS, module.export async property

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Building a web application with a nodeJS backend. I want to open a connection to the database in one place and then export this using module.exports. Here is the code:

```
let db;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/WIGAMEX', {
    poolSize: 50
}, (err, database) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error opening global mongo connection');
    }
    db = database;
});

module.exports = db;
```

However, the problem which I encounter is that the `db` variable get loaded in asynchronous and is not defined at the time the variable is exported. Therefore if we now import the variable in another file we will get `undefined`.

How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Either connect synchronously, or export a promise for the database.

Comment: Connect synchronously, how?

Comment: You can't directly export a value obtained asynchronously.  The export happens before the value is available.  You will have to implement an asynchronous interface for obtaining the `db` object.  See the question yours was marked a dup of and also this one: [Importing/Exporting after asynchronous result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310183/importing-exporting-only-after-certain-promises-have-resolved/38312566#38312566).