# Call async function out side function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have next code and sequence in which it runs is incorrect:

```
async function getItems(table) {
  return obj; // call 3, why it is called after module.exports and how to fix it
}

const {
var1,
var2
} = (async () => {
  await getItems('env-variables-feature'); // call 1
})();

exports = {
status: var1,
something: var2
};

module.exports = exports; // call 2
```

As I know await means we should wait until function execute

Comment: I'm not sure the second property desctructuring will work as you expect

Comment: Probably because of the IIFE `(async () => {
  await getItems('env-variables-feature'); // call 1
})();`. Why do you use an IIFE there?

Comment: how to do this in other way?

Comment: That await seems rather useless here.  You can't export something asynchronously.  Typically you export the async function itself and have the consumer of the package call the function they imported.

Comment: I'm not sure why people say it doesn't work: https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await

Comment: @jabaa they didn't await the function..  Would have needed `= await (async ...`

Comment: @Wyck That's in my first comment. The IIFE is the problem. Without the IIFE it should work.

Comment: @jabaa the IIFE calls an async function though.  So there's no way you can have the results of `getItems` by the time you are redy to export from your module.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38312566/1563833

Comment: @jabaa you mean just call getItems('env-variables-feature'); ?

Comment: @Wyck That was 2016. Things have changed since then. Top-level await is supported in Node.js and multiple browsers today.

Comment: @Ted `const { var1, var2 } = await getItems('env-variables-feature');`

Comment: @jabaa it fails: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: What is your Node.js version? You have to use a current version.

Comment: also would have needed to return as in : `await (async () => { return await getItems('env-variables-feature'); })();`  It's a bit of a mess.  Should just have `async function load() { const { var1, var2 } = await getItems('env-variables-feature'); return { status: var1, something: var2 }; }` and then export `load`

Comment: @Wyck You also should update your Node.js version. That's how you would solve it 2 years ago. `const { var1, var2 } = await getItems('env-variables-feature');` at top-level works in the current Node.js version

Comment: @jabaa I am using 12.14 and can't change it

Comment: You should use at least Node.js 16.13.0. That's the current LTS version. Why can't you change it?

Comment: @jabaa project requirements

Comment: @Ted Node.js 12 doesn't support it. You can export a function that returns a promise and you can await that promise, like Wyck explained in the comments.

Comment: I think this is a bad duplicate because the problem hinges on the module import/export mechanism and top-level await, not just how to use an async function or an async IIFE.